# Get headers from Spring Boot response in Angular 11

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to collect the headers that it sends in the Spring Boot response to an Angular client, the problem is that I cannot collect the values.
With Postman I can see them, but when I try it with Angular there is no trace of the headers. Any idea what is happening? Thank you!

**Controller Spring Boot:**

```
@GetMapping("/page")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllPageable(@PageableDefault(size = 10, page = 0) Pageable pageable, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Page<TodoEntity> result = todoService.findAll(pageable);
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        throw new TodoNotFoundException();
    } else {
        UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder =
                UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(request.getRequestURL().toString());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header("link", paginationLinksUtils.createLinkHeader(result, uriBuilder)).body(result);
    }
}
```

**Service Angular**

```
  getTodosPagination(page:number, size:number): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
const url = `${this.base_url}/todos/page/?page=${page}&size=${size}`;
return this.httpClient.get<any>(url,{
  headers: new HttpHeaders(),
  observe: 'response' });
```

**Component Angular**

```
  private getTodosPagination(page:number, size:number) {
this.todoService.getTodosPagination(page, size).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(
  (res:any)=> {
    console.log(res.headers)
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error["status"] == 404){
      this.todoCustom = [];
    }
  }
);
```

}

**Log in Spring Boot**
[image]

**Response with Postman with headers**

[image: Response with Postman]

**Response with Angular without headers**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must do :

1- Expose the headers link from your backend Spring-boot

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers in your backend to expose the link header
```

2- you must do in your Angular :

```
private getTodosPagination(page:number, size:number) {
    this.todoService.getTodosPagination(page, size).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(
      (res:any)=> {
        res.headers.get("link")
      },
      (error) => {
        if (error["status"] == 404){
          this.todoCustom = [];
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: Only 4 key pairs appear: value.
0: {"cache-control" => "cache-control"}
1: {"content-type" => "content-type"}
2: {"expires" => "expires"}
3: {"pragma" => "pragma"}
But link refuses to appear

Comment: you can use Access-Control-Expose-Headers in your backend to expose the link header to Angular client

Comment: Thank you very much friend!
@CrossOrigin (exposedHeaders = "*")
It worked

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as below.

```
return this.http.get<HttpResponse<Object>>(this.url, {observe: 
'response'}).pipe(
     tap(resp => console.log('response', resp))
);
```

Comment: Now I receive some headers that I could not see before, but the header with key 'link' I still cannot read it. Specifically I receive:
0: {"cache-control" => "cache-control"}
1: {"content-type" => "content-type"}
2: {"expires" => "expires"}
3: {"pragma" => "pragma"}
Where can the link be?

Comment: Request header only link there. Link not available in response header. You can verify by executing in browser and open F12 check what request repose header you have
..

Comment: It was necessary to expose the headers! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the HTTP Headers from the response like this

```
http
    .get<any>('url', {observe: 'response'})
      .subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp.headers);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The res.headers type is `HttpHeaders`, which is a class, not an object, so you can't get their property directly.

The correct way is:

```
console.log(res.headers.get('link'))
```

Official docs: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders